# Variables de una función a otra

Tags: php, laravel

tengo una vista llamada "solicitud", en esta vista tomo un request con todos los datos del formulario, entre ellos . después de este formulario tengo que enviar todos estos mismos datos sin guardar en la base de datos a otro formulario llamado "formulario_dua", en este formulario lleno otros datos y luego en el boton submit, deberia de guardar todos los datos completos del primer formulario y este ultimo.

Como puedo pasar todos las variables del primer formulario a controlador del 2do formulario para guardarlos en la base de datos?

Este es lo que tengo en la función del 1er formulario:

```
$solicitud = new solicitud;

   $tsol = $request->get('tsolicitud');
  if ($tsol == 1)
  {
    $doc5 = $request->file('doc5')->store('public');
    $doc6 = $request->file('doc6')->store('public');
    $doc7 = $request->file('doc7')->store('public');
    $persona = $request->get('persona');
    $empresa = $request->get('empresa');
    $tsolicitud = $request->get('tsolicitud');
    $carta = $request->file('carta_ministro')->store('public');
    $comentario = $request->get('comentario');
    $estado = 1;

    $ciudad = Ciudad::all();
    $usos = uso::all();
    $cuenca = cuenca::all();
    $acuifero = acuifero::all();
    $cagua = cuerpo_agua::all();
    $agro = agropecuario::all();
    $triego = riego::all();
    $cultivos = cultivo::all();
    $especies = especie::all();
    $animales = animal::all();
    $anio = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
     //dd($idsol);
    return \View::make('dgj.vwsolicitudes.vw_solicitud_dua',compact('ciudad', 'cuenca', 'acuifero', 'anio', 'cagua', 'persona', 'empresa', 'tsolicitud', 'carta', 'comentario', 'estado', 'doc5', 'doc6', 'doc7','usos', 'agro','triego', 'cultivos', 'especies', 'animales'));
```

Luego en la 2da funcion debería de guardar tanto los datos del primer formulario y el 2do formulario. Como puedo pasar las variables de la primera funcion a la segunda funcion?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las variables super globales aquí un ejemplo

```
function addition() { 
    $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y']; 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero aun tengo el problema, utilizo laravel 5.5 por cierto.

Comment: Esto es una muy mala práctica.

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas simple y "HTTP" de hacerlo es pasarle todos los datos validados del form A al form B y el form B los incluye con `<INPUT type="hidden"` asi vas encadenando y el formulario final contiene todos los datos de los formularios anteriores.

En tu caso está enviando los datos del form A a la vista siguiente (el form B supongo) por medio del `compact()` en la vista vas a tener disponible esas variables así que ahí es cuestión de armar los `input hidden` por ejemplo para ciudad:

```
{{ Form::hidden('ciudad', $ciudad) }}
```

Comment: Exactamente, eso mismo intenté, y funcionó en gran parte, el problema es con los input type file, esos no los guarda bien ya que el resultado que me da al traerlo del form A es "public/file.pdf", y de esa forma no puedo guardarlo.

Comment: el `->store('public')` es lo que guarda los archivos, y da como resultado el nombre del archivo guardado, no hace falta "guardarlo" de nuevo